# How to get a collection from firestore using data from another collection in react-Native.....What Am i Doing Wrong?

Tags: react-native

I have tried searching everywhere, from stackoverflow to GitHub but i can get a solution. I am trying to get list of users by using their userid that I get from a collection of businesses. What Am i doing wrong?

```
componentWillMount() {
//Loading all the business collections.
firebase.firestore().collection("business").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  var bizs = [];
  snapshot.forEach((bdt) => {
    var userdt = [];
    //get document id of a certain user in the business collections
    firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("userid", "==", bdt.data().userid).get()
      .then((snap) => {
        snap.forEach(dc => {
          //loading details of the user from a specific ID
          firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(dc.id).onSnapshot((udt) => {
            userdt.push({
              name: udt.data().fullname,
              photourl: udt.data().photoURL,
              location: bdt.data().location,
              openhrs: bdt.data().openHrs,
              likes: '20',
              reviews: '3002',
              call: bdt.data().contacts
            });
            console.log(userdt); //this one works
          })
          console.log(userdt); // but this one doesnt diplay anything just []
        })
      }).catch((dterr) => {
        console.log(dterr)
    })
  });
  this.setState({bizdata: bizs,loading: false
  });
});
}
```

I am using react-native and firestore

Answer (score 0):

Put log with some number, 
like,

```
       console.log('1',userdt);
       console.log('2',userdt);
```

and check weather which one is appearing first, Maybe '2' is executing before updating the data

Comment: Thank you. i solved it after struggling for several days